# FOSRestBundle: How to Avoid Automatic Pluralization of POST /login Route?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, pluralize

I have this Action to handle the user login also via REST api call:

```
/**
 * Login Action
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function postLoginAction(Request $request)
{
```

This is what `php app/console router:debug` shows me:

```
en__RG__post_login                          POST     ANY    ANY  /api/1/logins.{_format}
```

In this case the automatic pluralization to "**logins**" is not so nice... any ideas how to get only "**login**"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manage default route pluralization by overriding `fos_rest.inflector.doctrine` service. refer [this issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/247) and followed pull request.

or

for change pluralization of single route it can be done by using **Manual definition of routes**  please refer [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/7-manual-route-definition.html) from  FOSRESTBUNDLE repository

Comment: Awesome!
The manual definition was exactly what I needed!
* @Post("login")
Thanks!

Comment: [@ShawnNorthrop](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1076173/shawn-northrop) that was a useful edit I don't know why they rejected it, I'll update link#2