# Why Symfony FOS RestBundle adds 's' to the path for method POST?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

The current function is `postSignupAction()` in `UserController` class. after debugging route in command line i get `/users/signups.{_format}` whereas i expect `/user/signup`.

> public function postSignupAction(Request $request)
>   {
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   }

***But if i change the `post` to `get` in `postSignupAction()`,  everything will be as i expected. But i need it with POST method.***

Anyone can help?

Comment: UserController in FOS Rest Bundle ? O_o I have cloned this project from https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle, but there no UserController and no postSignup actions. Specify your problem, please.

Comment: btw, FOS Rest Bundle have no relation to your bundle routing.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way FOSRestBundle handles pluralization. By having a `postSignupAction` method inside your `UserController` class, FOSUserBundle understands the `user` instance has collection of `signup` instances.

You can either extend the `rest.doctrine.inflector` service to override this behaviour, or define your route manually with the `@Route` annotation.

Source: [FOSRestBundle: How to Avoid Automatic Pluralization of POST /login Route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394765/fosrestbundle-how-to-avoid-automatic-pluralization-of-post-login-route)